# Named CDI Bean with Interceptor - Memory Side Effect

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, java-ee-6, interceptor

In my project (JEE 6, JBoss 7.1, JDK 1.7), I have about 1000 @Named CDI, all inheriting from a common  @ConversationScoped abstract class.

I've noticed that if I define a new interceptor and I apply this interceptor to the  abstract (thus, applying it by inheritance to all the 1000 CDI beans mentioned before), it happens that the performance of the application is dramatically getting worse, both during the initial startup both during the normal activity.

I'm wondering if there's something wrong in what I did and if there's a way not to make the amount of memory increase so much, achieving the same goal, in order not to be forced to make such a change in all the production environments in which the application is deployed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Verify if it really is a memory leak by taking heap dump and analyzing it with Eclipse MAT: http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer . Maybe that interceptor simply is slow/has high overhead and it is not memory related.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I've already verified that just turning the interceptor on/off (comment / uncomment lines in "beans.xml") changes the amount of memory used by the application (about 20% more in "used heap") at startup.
The other point is that at startup this interceptor is never called (it will be called during the user activity, since it intercepts methods of Managed Backing Beans).

Comment: Hi all.
Does anyone have any idea about my issue, something that can help me to investigate the problem?
It seems like I'm missing something, but what?

Comment: Since you tag it java-ee-6, I assume you tried a java-ee-7 one and it does not happen there?

Comment: More memory usage is **NOT** necessarily a memory leak! Since to activate an interceptor CDI has to create a custom subclass of the bean class, the permgen grows accordingly, you may be observing just that.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos correct, what I previously (wrongly) assumed as a memory leak is not a leak; I observed that the increasement is proportional to the number of intercepted beans, and that's it; so, the question becomes if there's a way not to have this side effect, achieving the same goal.

Comment: @Kukeltje no, I haven't tried on tried a java-ee-7 yet; do you thimk that something could chamge?

Comment: No idea, java-ee-7 might have a newer implementation of CDI which might have things done differently. And on the other hand, is it an actual problem? If it is not a leak, what is "dramatically increases" (as stated in your other question? 10%? 100%?

Comment: yes, it's an actual problem, since we have a large number of production environment and implementing this new feature would force us to change memory settings on all these environments; with the interceptor on, the memory usage at startup is 25% more than with the interceptor off.